# aSmack PacketListener for custom IQProvider not working

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I have created a custom IQProvider class for a protocol I am trying to receive. The provider eppears to work fine, as an automatic response is not send back to the server about the message type not being implemented.

Here is my provider:

```
public class OA_IQProvider implements IQProvider{

public static final String NAMESPACE = "connect.logitech.com";
public static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "oa";
public static final String result = "RESULT";
private Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Override
public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception
{
    boolean stop = false;
    String name = parser.getName();

    while(false == stop)
    {
        switch (parser.getEventType())
        {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            {
                if(ELEMENT_NAME.equals(name))
                {
                    list.put(result, parser.getText());
                }

                break;
            }
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            {
                stop = ELEMENT_NAME.equals(name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    name = null;
    return new OA_IQ(list);
}

}

public class OA_IQ extends IQ
{
    public static final String ID = "servertime";
    private Map<String, String> list;

    public OA_IQ(Map<String, String> l)
    {
        list = l;
    }

    @Override
    public String getChildElementXML()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return list.get(OA_IQProvider.result);
    }
}
```

in My main activity I have added this provider:

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider(OA_IQProvider.ELEMENT_NAME, OA_IQProvider.NAMESPACE, new OA_IQProvider());
```

And i have implemented the following PacketListener:

```
        conn2.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet p) {
                Log.d(TAG, p.toXML());
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Packet.class));
```

I have also tried various other filters such as IQFilters.
In the debug log I do receive the message:

```
08-01 23:13:45.188  22174-23246/com.xxx.testingapp D/SMACK﹕ 11:13:45 PM RCV  (1105212208): <iq id="v3" to="guest" type="get"><oa xmlns='connect.logitech.com' mime='vnd.logitech.connect/vnd.logitech.pair' errorcode='200' errorstring='OK'><![CDATA[serverIdentity=xxx:hubId=97:identity=xxx:status=succeeded:protocolVersion={XMPP="1.0", HTTP="1.0", RF="1.0"}:hubProfiles={Harmony="2.0"}:productId=Pimento:friendlyName=xxx]]></oa></iq>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the identity from the server response. I have tried looking at the debug source code because basically what I am trying to accomplish is what the debug feature does already. But I couldn't find where the PM RCV was parsed.

Maybe my problem is that PM RCV is not catched by the PacketListener?